# Restoring of TRN file stucked in processing

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I am having a TRN file of around 30 GB and when I am restoring it by changing the location of mdf and ldf files to remote location and it is taking too much time i.e. 3-4 hours and still not showing any percentage starting of restoration.

When I have done same thing earlier with same for local VM or pc it was started in few minutes only.

SSMS version is 17.4
Remote locations for mdf and ldf files is window server 2008 R2.

Note:- I am not getting any error and the remote location is having enough memory to accommodate the expansion of the TRN file restoration.

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: I have to ask, why is your transaction file 30GB in size? That suggest you aren't taking very frequent transaction log back ups, *or* you had a *huge* amount of data changes that occurred in a short period of time. Also, what do you mean by you are "restoring it" by changing the location of the ldf and mdf files? That doesn't make sense as a "restore" operator. If you are restoring a database, you'll be using bak and trn files.  This sound like you're saying you have a database where its files are on a remote share; which is never going to work well.

Comment: @Larnu, as per the things in my local pc I am not having that much huge size in disc for restoring that file so I have got a remote location where I can specify the restore location. And yes the trn file is having so much data in it of years so that's why it is big.

Comment: So you are restoring the database, from a bak file(?) to a remote location? That isn't a good idea. The database should be stored locally. Performance for a using a database over the network will be awful and could *easily* cause corruption If you don't have enough space to store the database locally, you should be looking at upgrading your storage capacity or hosting the database instance elsewhere.

Comment: I am restoring from .trn file and their is nothing I can expand the current disk space and in remote location sql server is not working properly for trn files.